# Delete zeros from a sparse array

Tags: matrix, associations, sparse-arrays, rule

Why doesn't `SparseArray` automatically remove zero entries? The code

```
a = SparseArray[{2->22,3->33,5->55,7->77,11->1111,13->1313},13];
b = SparseArray[{1->11,3->33,5->55,7->77,9->99,11->1111},13];
r = DeleteCases[a-b,0]
r //ArrayRules
```

returns

> `{{1}->-11,{3}->0,{5}->0,{7}->0,{9}->-99,{11}->0,{2}->22,{13}->1313,{_}->0}`

instead of

> `{{1}->-11,{9}->-99,{2}->22,{13}->1313,{_}->0}`.

Is there a nice way to get rid of zero entries? For instance, when I perform Gaussian elimination on $A\!\in\!\mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}_2$, I use `A = Mod[A, 2];`, and suddenly many entries are zero. I don't want to waste memory on them.

Of course I could use

```
A = SparseArray[DeleteCases[ArrayRules[A], #[[2]] == 0&], {m,n}]
```

but it seems clumsy to use this often.

Also, when I have a very long sparse row that gets updated frequently and fills up somewhat (Gaussian elimination), is it better to use `SparseArray` with `+` or `Association` with `Merge`?

Comment: It does not do it automatically because rebuilding a sparse array is expensive. It is left to you to decide when you want to rebuild it and eliminate unnecessary entries. Just apply `SparseArray` again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just apply [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) to a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) object to normalize it. For your example:

```
a = SparseArray[{2->22,3->33,5->55,7->77,11->1111,13->1313},13];
b = SparseArray[{1->11,3->33,5->55,7->77,9->99,11->1111},13];
r = DeleteCases[a-b,0];

SparseArray[r] //ArrayRules
```

> {{1} -> -11, {2} -> 22, {9} -> -99, {13} -> 1313, {_} -> 0}